# Mysql Error: #1075

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1075

SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE  `blog` CHANGE  `id`  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

MySQL said:

```
#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

I am trying to create a blog, and I got the code done. Now, I need to make the `id` auto increase, but I get this error. Why am I getting this?

Answer (score 11):

MySQL is returning that error (most likely) because there is no unique index defined on the `id` column. (MySQL requires that there be a unique index. The other possibility, which you would have already figured out, is that there can be only one column defined as AUTO_INCREMENT within the table.)

To get that column to be an AUTO_INCREMENT, you can add either a UNIQUE constraint or a PRIMARY KEY constraint on the `id` column. For example:

```
ALTER TABLE `blog` ADD CONSTRAINT `blog_ux` UNIQUE (`id`) ;
```

(Note that this statement will return an error if any duplicate values exist for the id column.)

Alternatively, you can make the id column the PRIMARY KEY of the table (if the table doesn't already have a PRIMARY KEY constraint defined).

```
ALTER TABLE `blog` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ;
```

(Note that this statement will return an error if any duplicate value exist for the id column, OR if there are any NULL values stored in that column, of if there is already a PRIMARY KEY constraint defined on the table.)

Answer (score 7):

MySQL requires you to make auto increment column the primary key of a table. Add the `primary key` constraint at the end

```
ALTER TABLE  `blog` MODIFY COLUMN `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key
```

Comment: Just to clarify, MySQL does not require that a column be the primary key for a table in order to make it an AUTO_INCREMENT column. What MySQL requires is that there be a UNIQUE constraint on the column. A column that is the PRIMARY KEY column is eligible to be AUTO_INCREMENT; but it's not, strictly speaking, a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve `#1075 error` message you need to mark atleast one column as `primary_key` or `unique_key`. that you have forgot to do.

By defining `Primary _key` on **ID** column my error is resolved guys.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Also be aware if you put auto_increment on two columns it may still produce the error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).